# Signs of wear on new rollers

Tags: indoor, rollers

I recently bough a set of tacx antares rollers. I have been using them for about two weeks and i just noticed some signs of wear on them. Is it expected? Is it something that i should be worried about? I am worried that it may damage my tires. Should i claim the warranty on them? Thanks in advance.[image: roller wear]

Comment: This looks just like tyre wear. You have to expect some.

Comment: Are those black spots raised (deposits) or hollowed (erosion)?  My guess is that they are rubber from the tyre transferred to the roller. It looks like there are also flecks of tyre material on the floor, which is expected with any kind of stationary trainer where the resistance is applied to the tyre.

Comment: Which marks are you asking about?  But, frankly, I'd expect to see more signs of wear after 2-3 hours of use -- not worth worrying about.

Comment: +DavidW yes they are more like erosion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this looks like tyre wear. Due to friction, the tyre material is being abraded and partly it sticks to the roller surface and partly it falls on the ground in the vicinity.

This is normal and would be reduced with special tyres for indoor trainers. But if you want to move the bike in and out it might be awkward to change them. If you are going to only use the bike inside for the winter season, it may be worth a consideration.